# Get CameraX final resolution

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

Just created a camera preview in Android with CameraX with the following configuration:

```
    PreviewConfig previewConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
            .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(720, 720))
            .build();
    Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfig);
```

Now, the problem is that such target resolution may not be available, in which case the preview will choose a resolution closed to the requested one. What I'm asking here is a way to know which resolution has effectively be chosen by the preview.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it is possible. I've found out after a little bit of source code digging that after calling bindToLifecycle on your cameraProvider:

```
camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, previewUseCase, imageCaptureUseCase, analyzerUseCase)
```

You will be able to retrieve resolution selected for each applicable usecase:

```
val captureSize = imageCaptureUseCase.attachedSurfaceResolution ?: Size(0, 0)
val previewSize = previewUseCase.attachedSurfaceResolution ?: Size(0, 0)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Marcin, this will be useful for me when I update my project dependencies. I hope it's useful for @Dmytro Batyuk too.

Comment: `attachedSurfaceResolution` is library restricted now, we can use it suppressing the warning but we should ask for a new public API probably

Comment: Hey @Marcin Back

You can now use the unrestricted methods imageCaptureUseCase.getResolutionInfo().getResolution() (Java code). Would you like to update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found myself a solution.

```
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output) {
             ...
             Size resolution = output.getTextureSize();
             ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately CameraX doesn't provide such API any more. I haven't found alternative yet

Comment: @DmytroBatyuk I'm sorry to hear that. I hope they add something in a further version, or improve the docs explaining how things like this that should be pretty common can be done.

Comment: NP, just mentioned this for other people who are also looking for something similar to save their time

Comment: @DmytroBatyuk please check my answer. I've found a way to retrieve the final resolution.